# How do you set applicationIconBadgeNumber with scheduleLocalNotification?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I am having some difficulties setting the icon badge with a schedule local notification for my ios application.

I am able to trigger a local notification pop up after 10 seconds when I click the home screen after loading the application. However, the application icon badge number is not getting set. I am using the following code.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) return;
NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:10]; // adds 10 secs
localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
localNotif.alertBody = @"New Message!";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

I don't understand why the local notification pops up but the applicationIconBadgeNumber doesn't get set. I am able to set the icon badge number manually by executing the following code instead.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you debugging in the Simulator? Same problem on simulator but your code works fine on my iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, I just installed ios 4.3 and tested. It works on that. So it must have been a bug on the iphone 5 simulator.

Answer (score 3):

are you registering your application for all the badge notification type?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

also, check your notifications settings have not disabled badges.

Comment: question is about local notifications

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code for iOS 8+ in Swift...

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert , UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound], categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```